# jQuery Tabs UI and Ajax links issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

An ajax and tabs link puzzle. I've been through all the docs and SO and can't get this to work.

What works are the links Non-ajax Tab One. What doesn't work is a direct link to the tabs from another page or from a URL.

I.e., if I go to http://mydomain.com/ajaxloadedpage1/ I get the plain text of the content and not rendered in the tab. If I go to http://mydomain.com/#ajaxloadedpage1  I get the first tab Non-ajax Tab One.

How do I get the ajax page to load in the tab? Is it a complication that I am loading the ajax content via php and that the source file does not have the .html file suffix?

**Edit 2/11/11** Still not working, but I will add the fix when I figure it out.

**Header code**

```
ajax loader:

$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
        error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
            $(anchor.hash).html("I tried to load this, but couldn't. Try another link?");
            } 
        } 
    });
});


link enabler:

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs(); 
    $('.ajaxloadedpage1').click(function() { 
        $tabs.tabs('select', 1); 
        return false;
    }); });


(other links removed for clarity)
```

**Page code:**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul><a href="#tabs-1">Non-ajax Tab One</a></li>
<li><a id="#ajaxloadedpage1" href="http://mydomain.com/ajaxloadedpage1/"><span>Ajax Loaded Page1</span></a></li>
<li><a id="#ajaxloadedpage2" href="http://mydomain.com/ajaxloadedpage2/"><span>Ajax Loaded Page2</span></a></li>
<li><a id="#ajaxloadedpage3" href="http://mydomain.com/ajaxloadedpage3/"><span>Ajax Loaded Page3</span></a></li>
<ul>


<div id="tabs-1">Non-ajax Tab One</div>

//This tab has link to other tabs in this fashion, and they work

<a href="#ajaxloadedpage1" class="ajaxloadedpage1" title="Ajax Loaded Page1">Ajax Loaded Page1</a>

<a href="#ajaxloadedpage2" class="ajaxloadedpage2" title="Ajax Loaded Page2">Ajax Loaded Page2</a>

<a href="#ajaxloadedpage3" class="ajaxloadedpage3" title="Ajax Loaded Page3">Ajax Loaded Page3</a>
</div></div>


<div id="ajaxloadedpage1"></div>

<div id="ajaxloadedpage2"></div>

<div id="ajaxloadedpage3"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really have `#` in your `id` attributes? Your sample HTML say this:

```
<li><a id="#ajaxloadedpage1" ...
<li><a id="#ajaxloadedpage2" ...
<li><a id="#ajaxloadedpage3" ...
```

but I think you want to say this:

```
<li><a id="ajaxloadedpage1" ...
<li><a id="ajaxloadedpage2" ...
<li><a id="ajaxloadedpage3" ...
```

There are other cases like this too.

There is some special URL fragment mangling inside the jQuery-UI tabs to work around various browser bugs and oddities; that mangling could be hiding the problem when you're just clicking around but not when you get there through a URL.

Comment: Thanks; my mistake on the # on the ID, but it doesn't make a difference. Could the problem be that the ajax page being called is not a static html page but generated by php?

Comment: Different site, actually. The tabs on that site are not ajaxed, and all content is in one page, so the tabs "tab" on the same page and I don't have # direct URLs to tabs. The site in question is Wordpress, and I use a different page template for the ajaxed pages. If I use the default template with the complete header, the whole page loads in the tab, not just the ajax content; and the direct URL works to show the whole page, but not in the tabs. So I'm making some headway and it's a problem with what I'm loading in the page templates and I need to sort that out.

Comment: @songdogtech: This one works http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html#ui-tabs-3 and has an AJAX tab. So, at least the functionality works. Sounds like you're having issues with the content you're loading, correct? I'd hate to get the default half-bounty without actually getting your problem solved.

Comment: I'll take a look at the demo again; was kind of buried in other work this week and couldn't spend the time on this. No problem for me and the points; you helped. Seems like it is a page template problem with trying to get things into the tab. I'm going to keep working on it, as I need to get it to work for linking directy to tabs from other pages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but I use the cookie option for jQuery UI tabs like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs_start").tabs({
        cookie: {
        // store cookie for a day, without, it would be a session cookie
            expires: 1
        }
    });
</script>
```

This stores the tab I was using last time I visited a page. Just make sure your different tab sets have different ids.

Comment: I'm not using a cookie; I don't need to store the state of the tab, just access the tab via the full URL.

Answer (score 1):

did you look at the jQuery.load function? http://api.jquery.com/load/

example: load the #ajaxloadedpage div of ajaxloadedpage2.php into #ajaxloadedpage2:

```
$('#ajaxloadedpage2').load('ajaxloadedpage2.php #ajaxloadedpage');
```

Comment: This isn't part of Tabs ui, so I'm thinking there has to be a way within the Tabs ui to link with a full URL.

Comment: link to a full Url kinda defeat the purpose of Tabs, you just need to copy the CSS classes generated by ui tabs to your menu i think